# My code reads the last field with the first field of he next line from csv. Any advice fixing it please?

Tags: arrays, c, csv, struct

I want the program to read the last field of the line without reading the next field on the next line. I tried separating the lines with commas but in my opinion, it was not the correct approach to fix the problem. I saw some tutorial videos and all of them don't have to separate each lines with commas in the source csv file.

Here are the details about my code and my input file.

My struct defination:

```
typedef struct UserData{
    char NAME[50];
    char LAST[50];
    char TEL[11]; 
    } USER;
```

This is what my csv file look like:

```
test,test,1234567890
qwerty,qwertyy,0123456789
qqqqq,wwwww,1323284828
eeeee,rrrrr,4342424950
test1,test1,1234562234
```

This is my function used to read data in to struct:

```
int GetUserData(USER users[])
{
    FILE * file = fopen("test.csv", "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[1024]; //storing 1024 lines into buffer

    int row_count = 0;
    int field_count = 0;

    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) //inputting data in file to the struct
    {
        field_count = 0;
        row_count++;
        if (row_count == 1) continue; //Skip header
        char *field = strtok(buffer, ","); //separate buffer with commas
        while(field)
        {
            if(field_count == 0)
                strcpy(users[i].NAME, field);

            if(field_count == 1)
                strcpy(users[i].LAST, field);

            if(field_count == 2)
                strcpy(users[i].TEL, field);

            field = strtok(NULL, ","); //update field value
            field_count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    return row_count;
}
```

```
void PrintUserData(USER users[], int row_count)
{
    //printf("%d", row_count);                //row_count counts header which is ignored
    for(int i = 0; i < row_count - 1; i++){   //row_count has to be - 1
        printf("\nName: %s\nLast: %s\nTel : %s", users[i].NAME, users[i].LAST, users[i].TEL);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Name: qwerty
Last: qwertyy
Tel : 0123456789
qqqqq

Name: qqqqq
Last: wwwww
Tel : 1323284828
eeeee

Name: eeeee
Last: rrrrr
Tel : 4342424950
test1

Name: test1
Last: test1
Tel : 1234562234
```

I want the output to be like this instead:

```
Name: qwerty
Last: qwertyy
Tel : 0123456789

Name: qqqqq
Last: wwwww
Tel : 1323284828

Name: eeeee
Last: rrrrr
Tel : 4342424950

Name: test1
Last: test1
Tel : 1234562234
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the code you show, and not in the code that does the print-out (which you *don't* show)? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: I also recommend you take this time as the perfect opportunity to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Using a debugger you can step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: On a different note, your `while` loop could be replaced with `strcpy(users[i].NAME, field); field = strtok(NULL, ","); strcpy(users[i].LAST, field); // etc...`. There's really no need for the loop of the `field_count` cludge.

Comment: Aside: the delimiter string for `strtok` should be `",\n"` because `fgets` retains the newline.

Comment: I added the function that prints out the structs.

Comment: Possibly a side-effect of buffer overflow. Please show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that reproduces the fault.

Comment: Weather Vane raises a good point. Please show us the definition of your `USER` struct. If it has a field `char TEL[10]`, that's your buffer overflow right there.

Comment: and even `char TEL[11]` is too short, because of the newline retained.

Comment: Edit: I added my struct defination.

Comment: There you are: `char TEL[11]` but `"1234567890\n"` requires minimum `char TEL[12];`. Take out the newline [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109854/my-code-reads-the-last-field-with-the-first-field-of-he-next-line-from-csv-any#comment127411744_72109854) as you don't want it in the data anyway.

Comment: Thank you everyone in helping me finding the solutions. I've got my program fixed!. I've also learned many new things today. :D

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` leaves the line feed character of each line as the last character read. You can find it by calling `strrchr(field,'\n')` and then replace it with a `\0`.

Depending on how well you trust this file, it might be wise to check the string length of each substring before calling `strcpy`. In that case you can integrate the line feed check with that code:

```
size_t length = strlen(field);
if(field[length-1] == '\n')
{
  field[length-1] = '\0';
  length--;
}

if(length > TEL_SIZE) // a constant of value 10
{
  halt_and_catch_fire();
}

// strcpy code here
```

Comment: Let `strtok()` do the work.